# Counting presses of specific key on keyboard and decrease the count when other key is pressed in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, count, keycode, onkeydown

I am counting how many times the key "/" on the keyboard (keycode 111) was pressed. I am not able to figure out how to make it decrease if I press "Enter" (keycode 13).

Detailed description: Counting the press of "/", the number should be displayed in an HTML window. The function should check if the count number is bigger than 5. If it is, then after pressing "Enter" it will run function and decrease the number by 5, it displays the new number. If it isn't the "Enter" will be disabled.

I am newbie - Thank you for your help

here is the code I have so far:

```js
var Count = 0;

var input = document.getElementById('display');

input.onkeydown = function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if( key == 111 ){
        Count++;
        console.log( Count );
        return false;
    }
};
```

```html
<input id="display" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're checking the wrong key code for "/"

```js
var count = 0;

var input = document.getElementById('display');

input.onkeydown = function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    if(key === 13){
      count = (count - 5) < 0 ? 0 : count - 5
      input.value = count
      return false
    }
    if( key == 191 ){
        count++;
        console.log( count );
        input.value = count
        return false;
    }
};
```

```html
<input id="display" />
```

Comment: To clarify: There are two "/" keys on the keyboard "111 = divide" and "191 = forward slash". Question: Can it count regardless of where the cursor is, just by pressing the key on the keyboard? Perfect solution, great - Thank You!

Comment: Corrected `count = (count - 5) < 0 ? 0 : count - 5` is replaced with `count = (count - 5) < 0 ? value : count - 5` it will reach any number less than five without always ending with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if semantically correct, but here is the solution: it uses id of the web page container, thus anywhere on the page if pressed (onkeydown) the "/" =divide key from the numeric pad,  it adds 1, when "ENTER" key is pressed it subtracts 5, and displays remaining amount (for example 8-5=3). The result is placed in div with id="counter" inside the webpage. It works, but there is error when pressing "ENTER" after the amount is less than 5 (Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined), so definitely there must be "cleaner" solution to it.

```
 var count = 0;
 document.getElementsByClassName('container');
 document.onkeydown = function() {
 var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
 if(key === 13){
 count = (count - 5) < 0 ? value : count - 5
 document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count + " Points ";
 event.preventDefault()
 }
 if( key === 111 ){
 count++;
 document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count + " Points ";
 event.preventDefault()
 }
 };
```